# Prestashop webservice error 404

Tags: web-services, .htaccess, prestashop

I am trying to run a webservice from a script to prestashop (the example given with customers list). I receive the following error:

```
HTTP REQUEST HEADER
GET //api/customers&ws_key=57IGC8CC1HPC58U865KP7YNPWK1G4LSC HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic NTdJR0M4Q0MxSFBDNThVODY1S1A3WU5QV0sxRzRMU0M6
Host: edentalbook.com
Accept: */*

HTTP RESPONSE HEADER
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 17 Oct 2016 10:11:08 GMT
Server: Apache
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Content-Length: 320
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
RETURN HTTP BODY
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /api/customers&amp;ws_key=57IGC8CC1HPC58U865KP7YNPWK1G4LSC was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at edentalbook.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
Bad ID
```

I tested the server (I installed a fresh prestashop) and is working without problem. So I assume is a prestashop configuration issue.
Also I enabled friendly urls, htaccess

Any ideas? Thank you

Edited: Possibly it is a url rewrite issue because if i go from the server to http://edentalbook.com/webservice/dispatcher.php works perfectly
I attach the htaccess file

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule . - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]



#Domain: betashop.edentalbook.com
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling the CGI in the backoffice?

Comment: Yes..after some research I figured out that if I install the presta in subdomain (e.g. sub.example.com) it works. If it is installed in main domain (example.com) it doesnt. I applied the same configuration in both..

Comment: I dont know whether is relative but I just saw that the images are not displayed either when friendly url is activated. Is this htaccess issue?

Comment: However I read "Bad ID", that's not a full 404, are you sure of same configuration and permissions?
Imho you have to check server configuration, or SEO & URL PrestaShop configuration

Comment: what permissions should i use in files?

Comment: Not in file, I'm referring to WebService Key :)

Comment: aaa ok...I checked this also :(. Is it a possibility to be a url rewrite issue? The site is bilingual but when I entered in example.com/en/ images do not show..

Comment: If you want, add the .htaccess in the question. I'll take a look to it

Comment: .htaccess added. In access.log of the server i receive this `127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2016:16:01:20 +0200] "GET //api/customers&ws_key=35DPH1BUYNJACXT3VDGGNTETYKIXRCHV HTTP/1.1" 404 731 "-" "-"
`

Comment: The .htaccess looks ok... I don't understand your problem, if I go to [http://betashop.edentalbook.com/api/customers](http://betashop.edentalbook.com/api/customers) it ask to me the key ( that's seems not correct :) )

Comment: Yes in subdomain it runs but in normal domain it doesnt if I run it from php script.

Comment: I have the http login form also in the normal domain. [http://edentalbook.com/api/customers](http://edentailbook.com/api/customers), I guess you have a problem in the php script.

Comment: I took it from the examples as it is.That's why it gives me a headache. (P.S. it works in subdomain)

Comment: For some reason it looks for api in var/www/api and ofcource it cant  find it..

Answer (score 1):

Go to BackOffice -> Shop Parameters -> Traffic & SEO and hit the Save button in 'Set shop URL' block.
This will regenerate the .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permissions problem.

**Check if you use suPHP**
You can check if you have a permission problem by checking your error log (it will throw a SoftException)

If so, folders must be 755 and files 644

So if you have a SSH access you can easily fix with the find command.

First go to the path where the PrestaShop installation is in. Then:

**for files:**

`find . -type f -perm 666 -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

**for folders:**

`find . -type d -perm 777 -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, is this ok?